# How to use Djangosphinx

Tags: sphinx, django-sphinx

I have installed djangosphinx, but such commend 'generate_sphinx_config' is not able to be found. And I use sphinx beta2.0.1, but what is this version number of sphinx beta2.0.1

```
Note: You will need to install the sphinxapi.py package into your Python Path or use one of the included versions. To use the included version, you must specify the following in your settings.py file:
# Sphinx 0.9.9
SPHINX_API_VERSION = 0x116

# Sphinx 0.9.8
SPHINX_API_VERSION = 0x113

# Sphinx 0.9.7
SPHINX_API_VERSION = 0x107
```

Answer (score 1):

add djangosphinx to installed apps in settings